# Intermittent Issue with the USB port on the front of the case (working only after a reboot)

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, usb-flash-drive

I recently updated my PC setup and there seems to be a problem with the USB 3.0 port on the front of the case.

All other USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports are working well, but this single port behaves very strangely: sometimes it doesn't recognize 3.0 USBs plugged into it (only USB 3.0!) - it will only recognize them after a system reboot.

Thus I infer that this is a software problem (not a hardware problem with cables and stuffs). My system's OS is Windows 10 64 bit version 22H2 (build 19045.2006)

Follows is a screenshot of my Device Manager:
[image]

The one saying "USB Mass Storage Device" is what's added when the port does recognize the USB 3.0.

How should I proceed with this strange intermittent issue?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you have more than one USB 3.0 header on your motherboard? if so, try the other one